# How do you do an UPSERT in SQLite that is running in Expo?

Tags: sqlite, expo

I have a simplistic table like this

```sql
create table if not exists setup (
  key TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  value TEXT
)
```

Looking at the syntax for [UPSERT in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) I came up with this

```sql
insert into setup (key, value) values (?,?)
on CONFLICT (key) do update set value = ?
```

but I get

> Error: near "on": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Am I missing something in my upsert statement?  It looks okay when I read it.

I already tried backticking and putting the whole SQL into one line.

Comment: UPSERT is supported by SQLite since version 3.24.0. Check your version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like in Expo, they may be using an older version.  Since my requirements are simple this actually worked

```
insert or replace into setup (key, value) values (?,?)
```