# SQLite select followed by insert/update

Tags: javascript, sql, react-native, sqlite, expo

I'm trying to do the following sequence in SQLite in Expo, but it does not appear to consistently work.

```sql
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;  -- I tried immediate and deferred already
select id from artifacts where encryptedArtifactId = ?; -- I store the result

-- if resultSet size == 0
insert into artifacts ...

-- else if resultSet size == 1
update artifacts

-- finally
commit / rollback
```

But on random occurrences it gives me no results and tries to insert.

Am I missing some "flush" thing on SQLite

I am unable to do to my solution of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67911519/242042 since I am using a `PRIMARY KEY` that is `AUTOINCREMENT`.  I am also unable to do the SQLite 3.24 UPSERT operation since that's not available in expo or my device.

Comment: perhaps see `UPSERT` [How do you do an UPSERT in SQLite that is running in Expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911433/how-do-you-do-an-upsert-in-sqlite-that-is-running-in-expo)

Comment: That only works well if the table does not have an `autoincrement primary key` if there's an autoincrement, the primary key gets updated as well.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, can you not use [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_UPSERT.html) directly?

Comment: Expo SQLite does not support it *introduced in SQLite with version 3.24.0 *

Comment: Your code can be written without a separate SELECT statement. You need  an UPDATE and an INSERT statements which can include that SELECT statement.